# Commerce Multicurrency is not converting the field provided by the Commerce Free Price Formatter Module

Tags: commerce

I am using [Commerce Free Price Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_free_price_formatter) module so that I can show 'request' text if price is zero, but if price is more than 0, then **Commerce Multicurrency**  is not converting the currency if I go with Commerce Free Price Formatter.

Pls suggest any solution.